# Powershell script to validate sql syntax errors

Tags: sql, powershell

Is there any powershell syntax that detects sql syntax errors? For e.g. stored procedures , SQL query , functions etc.

Comment: You are looking for an Online SQL compiler like https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler

Comment: Yes . need a syntax validator written in powershell that will validate syntax errors.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? For SQL Server solution, see [earlier a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13316328/503046).

Comment: Microsoft sql server

Comment: You'd need to write an SQL parser for that (regardless of what DBMS you're using), which is clearly *way* beyond the scope of an SO question.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your query with `PARSEONLY` or `NOEXEC`, here's an example :

```
$Server = "SERVER"
$Database = "Database"
$UserId = "USERID"
$Password = "PASSWORD"
$QueryToTest= "SELECT * FROM NO_TABLE !!"

Function Check-Query-Syntax
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$query
    )
    try
    {
        $sb = New-Object -TypeName "System.Text.StringBuilder"
        [void]$classpath.AppendLine("SET NOEXEC ON;")
        [void]$classpath.AppendLine($query)
        [void]$classpath.AppendLine("SET NOEXEC OFF;")
        $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
        $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';User Id='$UserId';Password='$Password';trusted_connection=true;"
        $Connection.Open()
        $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
        $Command.Connection = $Connection
        $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
        $Reader = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $Connection.Close()
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Some error"
        throw
    }
}

Check-Query-Syntax $QueryToTest
```

[PARSEONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-parseonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
[NOEXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3276146/3759822

**UPDATE** :

If you want to check the queries inside `.sql` files then execute the script from the directory that contains the scripts

```
Get-ChildItem .\*.sql | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | ForEach { $query = (Get-Content -Path $_); Check-Query-Syntax $str }
```

Comment: Hi appreciate your efforts. Basically m trying to check the errors not through sql servers or anything. I have the sql scripts in my folder . I need it to check each file within the folder.

Comment: Yes .. thank you for that . Is it not possible without passing the database details etc? Is there any namespace available that will work in a way to display the errors?

Comment: @aishwaryamurali you need a connection to a SQL Server database server in order to validate a query because it's done on server side. Whats do you mean by "Is there any namespace available that will work in a way to display the errors?" ?