# Parse a SQL statement in SQL Server to check syntax validity - Similar to dbms_sql.parse in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I have a requirement in a project where some users insert some expressions in a table that later on will be added to a select statement for running a query. Before running the query itself in the final tool, I need to use a function to check the validity of the statement. Basically, I need to parse the statement to check the validity of the expression. The database is SQL Server 2014.

I know how to do it in Oracle using this small piece of code:

Oracle

```
create or replace function check_sql( p_sql in CLOB ) return boolean
authid current_user
is
v_cur int;
begin
v_cur:= dbms_sql.open_cursor();
dbms_sql.parse(v_cur,p_sql,dbms_sql.native);
dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cur);
return true;
exception
when others then
return false;
end;
/

SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
SQL> declare
v_result varchar2(20);
is_ok boolean;
begin
  is_ok := check_sql ( 'select 1 from dual' ) ;
  if is_ok
  then 
    v_result := 'OK' ;
  else
    v_result := 'ERROR' ;
  end if;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
end;
/

OK

SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
SQL> declare
v_result varchar2(20);
is_ok boolean;
begin
  is_ok := check_sql ( 'select 1 from duala' ) ;
  if is_ok
  then 
    v_result := 'OK' ;
  else
    v_result := 'ERROR' ;
  end if;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
end;
/

ERROR
```

Can anyone tell me how to do something similar, if possible, in Transact SQL?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `SET PARSEONLY ON` probably does what you need - see answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316328/ways-to-validate-t-sql-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about combination of sp_prepare and sp_unprepare:

```
DECLARE @P1 INT;  
DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(200) = N'SELECT database_id, name FROM sys.databases'
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_prepare @P1 OUTPUT, NULL, @Cmd;  
    EXEC sp_unprepare @P1
    PRINT N'CORRECT'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT   
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
    PRINT N'INCORRECT'
END CATCH
```

Incorrect statement will throw an exception

```
DECLARE @P1 INT;  
DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(200) = N'SELECT database_id, name FROM sys.databases2'
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_prepare @P1 OUTPUT, NULL, @Cmd;  
    EXEC sp_unprepare @P1
    PRINT N'CORRECT'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT   
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
    PRINT N'INCORRECT'
END CATCH
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. How can I add this to a procedure in transact sql that accepts the table name as input parameter ?